# Wall stud in the way of vent hood exhaust

Tags: studs, exhaust-vent

So I am in the midst of hanging a new vent hood in my kitchen and as luck would have it there is a stud nearly centered on where the vent hood exhaust needs to be.

[image]

[image]
Looking for advice on the best way to proceed.

- up is not an option as the house is 2 stories
- at best there is 3.5" on either side of the stud
- the manual warns against using anything smaller than 6.2" Duct (not sure if that suggestion can be ignored)

My best idea at this point is to cut the stud...but I am not really sure how I would get it cut.

Comment: Is that armored cable in there too? If so, can it safely be moved far enough for the vent hardware?

Comment: @Andrew Morton That is where the 220 line drops in for the oven. There is enough slack that I can push it to the side when I install the vent.  The 110 line there is the power source for the hood so I can move that wherever

Comment: Presumably this is an exterior wall so load bearing?

Comment: @StrongBad Yes an exterior wall

Comment: Which way do the ceiling joists/trusses run: in-and-out in the picture or side to side? Is it possible to go up into the inter-floor space and then out the rim joist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to cut the stud, install 2 rectangular ducts on each side of the stud and split the original duct into two. if the two rectangular ducts have a combined area greater than that circular one, you wont have issues with flow restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch.. yes this should have been researched a bit ago, if you are re-doing the kitchen, before the cabinets went up.   If you want to cut that stud, you should open up the wall as much as necessary (this is the tricky part) to put in a doubled lateral plate, and then two new cripple studs above and to either side of your proposed duct location.  (sort of like how windows are framed)

An alternative would be to get a hood that is wider or doesn't require a vent down the center.